# Which lifetime manager to use to create new instances in foreach loops using Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I got an example where I want to use DI to create instances of a class in a foreach loop but cannot figure which lifetime manager to use. The default lifetime manager will obviously only use the instance injected in the controller where I want to create new instances each time the instance is called as illustrated in the example below. I'm using Microsoft Unity

Simple interface class

```
public interface ISomeClass 
{
    string GetValue(string value);
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    public string GetValue(string value) 
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Register in container

```
container.RegisterType<ISomeClass, SomeClass>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Implementation

```
private readonly SomeClass _someClass;

public MyController(SomeClass someClass)
{
    _someClass = someClass;
}

// someStringList would contain values like "hello", "world", "o", "hai"
public void Whatever(List<string> someStringList) 
{
    List<string> otherStringList = new List<string>();

    foreach (var someString in someStringList)
    {
        // _someClass.GetValue will simply return the same value
        otherStringList.Add(_someClass.GetValue(someString));
    }

    // otherStringList contain as many elements as the someStringList 
    // but all will be the same as the last element in the list
}
```

Comment: First thing, why are you inserting concrete type instead of the interface? One possible solution could be to create a factory interface and create the new instance within the for loop...

Comment: @Johnny yea I can see my example was a bit messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TransientLifetimeManager` lifetime manager is the way to go. That one will create new object each time you, or container itself, call `Resolve`.

---

So the point is to initiate that `Resolve` somehow within the `foreach`. The naive\simple approach could be to inject `IUnityContainer` itself into your controller, the `IUnitContainer` itself is always available...

```
private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

public MyController(IUnityContainer container)
{
    _container = container;
}
```

then resolve `ISomeClass` manually:

```
foreach (var someString in someStringList)
{
     var someClass = _container.Resolve<ISomeClass>();
     otherStringList.Add(_someClass.GetValue(someString));
}
```

---

Generally, I would prefer more some kind of factory or prototype pattern instead of injecting the `IUnityContainer` itself as that might be considered as a bad practice. The container should be used more as *an invisible helper* instead of first class citizen...

The easy factory approach can be to register the simple factory method:

```
_container.RegisterType<Func<ISomeClass>>(new InjectionFactory(_ => 
            new Func<ISomeClass> (() => _container.Resolve<ISomeClass>())));
```

then you can inject this into your controller:

```
private readonly Func<ISomeClass> _factory;

public MyController(Func<ISomeClass> factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
}
```

and then you it as:

```
foreach (var someString in someStringList)
{
     ISomeClass someClass = _factory();
     otherStringList.Add(_someClass.GetValue(someString));
}
```

The good thing about the second approach is that you have explicit dependency instead of injecting IoC, which makes your design cleaner.

Comment: The second example is way cleaner as you say and replacing the `_container.Resolve<ISomeClass>()` with `_container.Resolve<SomeClass>()` made it work.